# Safe Power rating of resistor for my circuit

Tags: voltage, power, resistors, heat, protection

I am working on circuit shown below[image: Power]

Current flowing through circuit is 88.235 mAmp

I = V/R = 24/272 = 88.235mA

which generates heat of

68*88.235*88.235 =  0.529 Watt

I have used resistors of 1 watt but it generates little heat.

> Will this resistor sustain for longer time?

or

> should I increase the wattage?

Comment: How does the heat leave the circuit? airflow forced? airflow of convection, inside a closed box? conduction through solder terminals through bakelite insulation down to steel chassis? or are the resistors installed on a PCB, as throughlead, and the heat has to flow through the FR-4 epoxy fiberglass down to various planes (GND and VDD), before leaving the PCB.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf yes circuit is inside the closed box. Resistors are installed on PCBs  and they are SMD resistors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking whether a 1 W resistor is OK with a sustained 0.53 W power dissipation?

Yes, that is fine within reason. The resistor will get hot, that's normal, the power is turned to heat and it will be designed to cope with that heat under normal circumstances. If you were to put it in an oven, in a vacuum, or cover it in thermal insulation then things could be different. But if it's sitting in a normal room then it won't be a problem.

It may also be an issue if all 4 resistors are pushed up next to each other, leave some space between them.

A higher wattage rated resistor will get almost as hot, it will still be getting the same amount of heating but it will normally be larger giving it more surface area to use for cooling.

Comment: +1 good answer. I'd also add how the resistor is mounted and connected also matters. The 1W rating is for a specific lead length and connection type. Longer leads, fatter pads and traces (or wires), component touching the PCB can all significantly alter the temperature coefficient of the device.

Answer (score 0):

24 volts x 88.235 mA is a total power of 2.18 watts and this power is equally shared amongst the 4 resistors hence each dissipates 0.53 watts. Using 1 watt resistors should be fine but read the data sheet for the resistors and analyse your hardware to see if the temperature can reach a level where you need to de-rate the wattages of the resistors.

Comment: Should I use resistor with 2 wattage capacity?

Comment: Read the data sheet and analyse your hardware. I can't be clearer than that. I know nothing about your set-up nor do I know what ambient temperatures you are likely to self-generate or encounter in normal use. 8 out of ten applications will be fine with 1 watt resistors and they will get warm over time.